# Where does "reach-me-down" (as a variant of hand-me-down) come from

Tags: etymology

A houseful of native British English speakers has never come across this variant, but it appears in the dictionary [(Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reach-me-down). [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reach-me-down) has *noun, adjective British. hand-me-down.*

So where does this version come from? It's not new (1860s according to dictionary.com).  There's speculation at [wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/reach-me-down.663171/) that it's a regional variation, but nothing conclusive.

Comment: As a native Brit speaker, I had only ever heard of 'hand-me-down'. From the Ngram it looks as though 'reach-me-down' is going out of favour in AmE https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hand+me+down%2Creach+me+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chand%20me%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creach%20me%20down%3B%2Cc0

Comment: While not the same meaning, I've heard "reach me down" in the American south in the sense of retrieving something too high to reach for someone else. "Be a dear and reach me down that jar of pickled okra?"

Comment: @barbecue that's in general use here in the UK as well. It makes searching harder

Comment: @ChrisH To try to find usage examples, you could try pluralizing it to "reach-me-downs" to reduce results from the alternate meaning.

Comment: @barbecue the hyphens help as well, but nothing gives anything about where it is/was in wide use.

Comment: @ChrisH The OED has some interesting details. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/158825

Comment: @ChrisH It looks like Reach-me-down originally was another term for ready-made items. OED offers "Ready made" and "Off-the-peg" as synonyms for this usage. A reach-me-down suit or gown might be called "off-the-rack" today, as opposed to a tailor-made or bespoke product. 
This usage seems to have been popular in the late 1800s, but over time it came to mean items of mediocre quality, and eventually second-hand or used items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of sources agree on the date in  which it was apparently  first used, that is 1862.

> [Reach-me-down](https://www.etymonline.com/word/reach) "ready-made" (of clothes) is recorded from 1862, ***from notion of being on the rack in a finished state.***

(Etymonline)

From the Routledge Dictionary of Historical Slang and the [Dictionary of Slang and unconventional English](https://books.google.it/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA964&lpg=PA964&dq=reach%20me%20down%20from%20partridge%20dictionary%20of%20unconventional%20english&source=bl&ots=_3KAfIuJ1M&sig=Yzqscm7FCyOgXvB0vYBos8keu-s&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit0sDBn6PYAhXF6xQKHUc-CvMQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=reach%20me%20down%20from%20partridge%20dictionary%20of%20unconventional%20english&f=false)  by Eric Patridge:

***[Reach-me-down](https://books.google.it/books?id=JRuNMHNcu5cC&pg=PA4325&lpg=PA4325&dq=thackeray%20besant%20%26rice&source=bl&ots=6jDOLJUHlo&sig=Sop8wa6hdXBEZ6FbusYQaZfEGkc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC3Z2FnaPYAhWHblAKHVFcCuMQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=thackeray%20besant%20%26rice&f=false) :***

> ***adj. 1862*** (Thackeray; Besant & Rice).  *Ready-made, or occ. second-hand, clothes; in late C.19–20, often of such, hence of any, trousers: perhaps always S.E. (ex U.S.). Coll. reacher*.

It appears that ***hand-me-down*** has a later origin:

> Something, esp clothing, used by one person and then passed to another, esp to a younger sibling : I wore mostly my brother's hand-me-downs ([1874+](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hand-me-down))

(The Dictionary of American Slang, Fourth Edition)

Answer (score 1):

[*OED*](http://oed.com/) offers as its earliest attestation of the adjective 'reach-me-down', in the sense of "ready-made", an 1861 quote from Thackeray's [*The Adventures of Philip on His Way Through the World*, as published in the November issue of *Cornhill Magazine*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101076403359;view=1up;seq=564).

> You know in the Palias Royal they hang out the most splendid *reach-me-down* dressing-gowns, waistcoats, and so forth. "No," thought Philip..."My brown velvet dress waistcoat...is a much more tasty thing than these gaudy ready-made articles."

The adjective, however, was well-known by 1861, and shows up in print at least as early as 1844:

> His "smalls" were white...they looked as if they had not been "made to measure," but had more of the cut of the Blue-coat School, or a "*reach-me-down* shop."
>
> [*American Turf Register and Sporting Magazine*, September 1844](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b3246441;view=1up;seq=571).

Significance should not be attached to the first appearance I found being in a US publication: the article's author is Lord William Lennox, and it deals with English horse racing.

Of the adjective, *OED* notes "Also in later use: cast-off, second hand." The finding that the sense of 'cast-off' appeared later corresponded with my own, and suggests that 'reach-me-down' did not originate as a regional variant of 'hand-me-down'.

*OED* attests noun usage of 'reach-me-down' from 1861, but the earliest use as a noun I found was from 1849:

> ...the Dean, who was never very particular in his dress, encased himself in a very ill-shaped, ready-made-looking, great-coat, a regular "*reach-me-down*" from a slop shop in St. Mary Axe, ....
>
> [*Sporting Magazine*, June 1849](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uiug.30112105834649;view=1up;seq=457).

Of the use as a noun, *OED* again notes "In later-use *esp.*: an article of second hand clothing; a hand-me-down."

---

About 'hand-me-down', *OED* attests the adjective from 1826 and notes "Occasionally also: ready made, as opposed to tailored; off-the-peg." So too is the *OED* note concerning noun use of 'hand-me-down' (1835) weakened: "(also) a ready-made garment (now rare)."

---

Precative or jussive use of the older verbal phrases 'hand me down' and 'reach me down' may be synonymous, that is,

> Hand me down that suit [from the clothes rail in a shop].

may be used as the semantic equivalent of the colloquial

> Reach me down that suit [etc.].

and vice versa. The possibility of such synonymous use of the verbal phrases explains the "occasional" (*OED*) noun, and "now rare" (*OED*) adjectival, uses of 'hand-me-down' in the sense of "ready-made" more usually associated with 'reach-me-down'. Equally, that possibility of synonymy explains the opposite, wherein the colloquial 'reach-me-down' is used to mean 'hand-me-down' in the sense of "[something] passed on".

Contributing to the weak tendency to use 'hand-me-down' to mean 'reach-me-down', and vice versa, is a conspicuous empirical association: both "passed on" and "ready made" clothes often fit poorly.

The possible synonymy of the two terms, and their conspicuous empirical correspondence, are where "'reach-me-down' (as a variant of 'hand-me-down') comes from".